# php curl POST request in foreach loop, it's not adding all the records into Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, woocommerce

I am trying to import bulk products into Woocommerce store using php CURL's. I've 1000 products data in an array but upon code execution it only adds 200 products or 280 and sometimes 170 only. It would be really great if someone can point out mistakes from my code or guide me into right direction.
Thanks!

```
 // this $arrajson holds 1000 products records
    $loopdata = array();
    foreach ($arrajson->data as $value) {

           $data = [
        'name' => $value->attributes->product_name,
        'type' => 'simple',
        'regular_price' => '21.99',
        'sku' => $value->attributes->part_number,
        'description' => $value->attributes->part_description,
        'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
        'categories' => [
            [
                'id' => 9
            ],
            [
                'id' => 14
            ]
        ],
        'images' => [
            [
                'src' => $value->attributes->thumbnail
            ],
            [
                'src' => $value->attributes->thumbnail
            ]
        ]

    ];
    $loopdata []= $data;
    }
    //Successfully got 1000 records here $loopdata
    forech ($loopdata as $value){
       $sData = json_encode($value);
       //print_r($sData);

      $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://staging.example.co/wp-json/wc/v3/products");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $consumerKesy.":".$consumerS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($sData))                                                                       
        );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        $errors = curl_error($ch);

    }
    //echo "Here it is".$ch;
    curl_close ($ch);
    }
```

Comment: maybe its not giving the request enought time only, just a guess. Try: put usleep(1000000) or sleep(1) (or less time) in the script and give it some more time , maybe that works better.

Comment: What is the error after the 201 product not being added?? Always include errors...

Comment: @Ron I don't get a single error.

Comment: @Rustyjim Got it. Gonna Try.

Comment: @Rustyjim i tried with sleep in loop and also tried with CURLOPT_TIMEOUT but no progress.

Comment: It is solved now, I've handled it by Ajax.